# Facebook emotions animation

Tags: javascript, facebook

Does anyone have an idea about how facebook is animating it's png sprite animations? 
I managed to do something but it's kind of hard coded:

`<div data-instances="18" data-h="4" data-w="5" id="general-1"></div>`

This tells me that I have 18 instances, with 5 columns and 4 rows (max 20 instances). From this line results that on the last row I have 2 blank instances.
I did the JavaScript to animate the sprite but I think there's gotta be an easier way...
thanks

Comment: well you could use the css animate for instance... Why would you like to do it exactly  like them? There may be simpler or more elegant ways...

Comment: To be honest I don't :) but that's the request... I have some png sprites and they have to be like fb